# Replace prepositions and articles in excel with words using a named range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, text-formatting

i have created a sheet to paste in text and output lower, UPPER, and Proper text
I have a named range of prepositions and articles capitalizerd.

I am trying to use the SUBSTITUTE formula to replace all the occurrences or words that appear in the prepositions list

so instead of

```
Our Breakfast Is Consistent
```

We get

```
 Our Breakfast is Consistent
```

so far I have this formula, but it does not work

```
=SUBSTITUTE(D6, TRIM(prepositions), TRIM(LOWER(prepositions))
```

Can anyone help. Would be very appreciated

Thanks

Andi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a user defined function

```
   Function prep_lower(the_text)

    Dim prep_list(10, 10)

    prep_list(1, 1) = "As"
    prep_list(1, 2) = "as"

    prep_list(2, 1) = "Or"
    prep_list(2, 2) = "or"

    prep_list(3, 1) = "Is"
    prep_list(3, 2) = "is"
    'more items......


    For n = 1 To UBound(prep_list, 1)
    the_text = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(the_text, Chr(32) & prep_list(n, 1) & Chr(32), Chr(32) & prep_list(n, 2) & Chr(32))
    Next 'For n = 0 To...

    prep_lower = the_text



    End Function
```

then enter text in, say, cell a1 and the formula `=prep_lower(A1)` in b1

Comment: Excel for MAc 2008 does not come with VBA support. That's why I've been trying to use a function to do the job. However thank you for this I can utilize this and do it in PHP...

Comment: @user1712691, glad it helped; sure in PHP, it will be a no brainer.I least I learned something about Excel on Mac!

Comment: No Worries. I'm going to attempt the PHP script this weekend. I'll be pasting up on here for everyone to use. :o)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `SUBSTITUTE` to replace lists in one hit - you need to `SUBSTITUTE` one item at a time, so if you have prepositions in F2:F5, for example you could use a formula like

`=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(D6,F2,LOWER(F2)),F3,LOWER(F3)),F4,LOWER(F4)),F5,LOWER(F5))`

Of course if you have a long list that isn't very practical, in which case you could possibly copy down (or across) a formula which would potentially replace one value at a time, e.g. with the above example use this formula in D7 to D10

`=SUBSTITUTE(D6,F2,LOWER(F2))`

D10 will be the final value with all substitutions

Comment: hi There, I figured it's easier to do this in PHP rather than excel. Set up a form with options and use some regular expressions to output the kind of text I need. - Thanks Andi

Answer (score 0):

I figured it's easier to do this in PHP rather than excel. Set up a form with options and use some regular expressions to output the kind of text I need.

I will once I have created the HTML and PHP will post the example here.
I will also do it as an option to upload a CSV, read from it and then it will output in a way you can see. With an export back to CSV with amends.

This might be useful then for anyone facing the same problem.

Thank you to the kind users who posted solutions to this problem I had.

Thanks

Andi